# How to use while loop for the date in mysql stored procedure and insert records into database

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want add the records as a single row in the database from FROMDATE to TODATE.but the problem is it only insert record for one month...

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCalendar`(IN `INPFROMDATE` DATE, IN `INPTODATE` DATE)
     NO SQL

```
BEGIN

DECLARE SFROMDATE DATE;
DECLARE STODATE DATE;
SET SFROMDATE=INPFROMDATE;
SET STODATE=INPTODATE;

WHILE SFROMDATE<=STODATE
DO

INSERT INTO CALENDER VALUES(SFROMDATE,STODATE);
SET SFROMDATE=SFROMDATE+1;
END WHILE;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find the next date by incrementing a DATE type value (SFROMDATE in your example). You need to use [DATE_ADD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) like:

```
SET SFROMDATE=DATE_ADD(SFROMDATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```